# Display XML bounds XSL into a HTML Web Page

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I've been searching for the solution hours and hours but still can't display my XML table between div tags. I'm sure html codes are correct because I can put some bootstrap list and display them. And also I can reach xml file bounds xsl, it works fine too. But when I write xsl codes into my html page's div tags it shows some broken table. I think it doesn't get data.

this is my xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">



<xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
        <body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">Ad</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Soyad</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Devamsızlık</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Not</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="cmf/ogrenci">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="ad"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="soyad"/></td>


                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="devam > 3 ">
                        <td bgcolor="#5882FA">Devamsızlıktan Kaldı
                            (<xsl:value-of select="devam"/>)
                        </td>

                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="devam"/></td>

                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not &lt; 60 ">
                        <td bgcolor="#A9F5BC">Sınavdan Kaldı
                            (<xsl:value-of select="not"/>)
                        </td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="not"/></td>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>


            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
        </body>
</html>

</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is my xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tablo.xsl"?>
<cmf>
    <ogrenci>
        <ad>Gökhan</ad>
        <soyad>Şen</soyad>
        <devam>6</devam>
        <not>60</not>
    </ogrenci>
    <ogrenci>
        <ad>Mustafa</ad>
        <soyad>Gürdal</soyad>
        <devam>2</devam>
        <not>80</not>
    </ogrenci>
    <ogrenci>
        <ad>Mehmet</ad>
        <soyad>Bulut</soyad>
        <devam>1</devam>
        <not>25</not>
    </ogrenci>
    <ogrenci>
        <ad>Veli</ad>
        <soyad>Uysal</soyad>
        <devam>3</devam>
        <not>90</not>
    </ogrenci>
    <ogrenci>
        <ad>Cemal</ad>
        <soyad>Yalçın</soyad>
        <devam>0</devam>
        <not>95</not>
    </ogrenci>
    <ogrenci>
        <ad>Sinan</ad>
        <soyad>Sinanoğlu</soyad>
        <devam>15</devam>
        <not>55</not>
    </ogrenci>
    <ogrenci>
        <ad>Ahmet</ad>
        <soyad>Pak</soyad>
        <devam>2</devam>
        <not>48</not>
    </ogrenci>
    <ogrenci>
        <ad>Ayşe</ad>
        <soyad>Tellioğlu</soyad>
        <devam>0</devam>
        <not>75</not>
    </ogrenci>
    <ogrenci>
        <ad>Mehmet</ad>
        <soyad>Eroğlu</soyad>
        <devam>2</devam>
        <not>55</not>
    </ogrenci>
    <ogrenci>
        <ad>Leyla</ad>
        <soyad>Kutlu</soyad>
        <devam>8</devam>
        <not>88</not>
    </ogrenci>



</cmf>
```

I want to call that xml between here.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center"> here </div>
```

my xml works with xlst fine normally when I reach only to it.
[you can check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7egCR.png)

Thanks in advance.

ps: I'm newbie on xml xsl, maybe I miss really important subject.

Comment: The only strange bit I see is that the XSL lacks the root closing node. What's exactly the problem?

Comment: I edited it, I couldnt copy closing node. The problem is I can't show this table into my html page. XSL doesnt work properly, I guess it can't read XML data. Because i see some broken xsl table on the html page. Normally as you can see from the image xml works very well with xsl when I reach directly tablo.xml from the server. I want to show that xml(which works fine with xsl) on my index.html. index.html is working fine responsively I can add what I want and it works nice, I mean there is no fails in html code.

Comment: @celnmeh how you are doing transformation? Are you dependent on browsers built in transformation or you are using client side XSL transformation or server side transformation?

It seems you are trying to include xsl in html?

Comment: @TechBreak Do you mean by transformation some httprequest functions? No, I didn't use any of them. I just wrote xml and xsl code and trying to copy xsl directly to between div tags.

Comment: @celnmeh i meant that we would like to know which transformation you are doing? Client side transformation (browser dependent or javascript based) or server side using say java? In general your file should be with extension .xsl and it should set output as html and provide it your XML. You can refer 
http://www.way2tutorial.com/xml/converting_xml_to_html_using_xsl_transform.php

Comment: @TechBreak It's browser dependent. I didn't write anything except xml and xsl. Thanks, I will refer that link.

Comment: I found the solution. I missed a serious part. I used xsl client side transform to create my object. I could display my xml bounds xsl in my html page. Reference http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp